# How to force a connection to a a2dp bluetooth device by an activity or service

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth

I'm using my Nexus One with Android 2.2 Froyo in my car dock. For the audio output I'm using a a2dp receiver which is hooked up to my car stereo.
Now, when I put the phone in the car dock it automatically connects to the car dock but not to my a2dp receiver, I have connect it manually in the settings (already paired).

I'm also using a custom app for audio playback. I thougt I maybe could force the a2dp connection to the a2dp receiver. But as far as I know, the default Bluetooth API does not support such a thing.

Is there any Intent for establishing the connection, or any other way? I would also accept an undocumented solution.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this recently with the app A2DP volume.
My issue was my lg p920 on android 2.3.5 would connect to handsfree and a2dp stereo audio with my Sony car stereo mex bt3950ou (many other brands have the same issue).

Once the car was turned off and back on again ie. in turning the ignition from acc to start, the connection would be lost and only the handsfree would reconnect.

A2DP volume can be configured to force reconnect the stereo audio connection, see instructions on the A2DP volume site.

Answer (score 0):

See your issue with twin BT devices. You can get BT Visor mount systems that do this. The BB version will stream A2DP music from the device AND allow you to take calls. The drawback is it uses FM to get the sound to your headunit so sound quality will be lower than native BT.

Answer (score -1):

The technique is demonstrated in this app: http://code.google.com/p/a2dpvolume/[A2DP Volume](http://code.google.com/p/a2dpvolume/)

Look at service.java and the IADL file.